# How to use vue js 3 route on dynamic url with 404 page?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

I have single page site i.e xyz.com, in this page i'm checking routes for some dymanic urls and 404 page.

When i'm accessing url like **xyz.com/p1**, **xyz.com/p2**...etc. Routes are working as expected but when accessing any invalid url like **xyz.com/invalid** then it's redirecting correctly on **NotFound** component but at the same time it's updating the url.

**e.g:** if i access **xyz.com/invalid** then url get changed **from** *xyz.com/invalid* **to** x*yz.com*.

1. How do i retain url as it is if someone access invalid url and it should redirect to NotFound component i.e 404 page.
2. if i access url like **xyz.com/invalid/** (adding extra slash at the end) then it's show blank white page instead of NotFound page ? ideally anything comes after first slash except dynamic url **p1, p2, p3**....etc that should redirect to NotFound page.

Any help ?

Below is the code snippet:

**main.js:**

**Note:** productArray contain 'n' no. of products.

```
var productArray = [
  {
    label: "product1",
    code: "p1",
  },
  {
    label: "product2",
    code: "p2",
  },
  {
    label: "product3",
    code: "p3",
  }
];

const routes = [{
    path: "/:product",
    component: Home,
    beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
      const item = to.params.lang;
      if (productArray.find((e) => e.code == product) == undefined) {
        next({ name: "notFound"});
      } else {
        return next();
      }
    },
  },
  {
    path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*",
    name: "notFound",
    component: NotFound,
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    redirect: 'p1',
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

let app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);
app.mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 0):

preserve the current path with the `params` property included in your call to `next`

```js
next({
  name: 'notFound',
  params: { pathMatch: to.path.substring(1).split('/') }
})
```

Comment: 2nd issue is not resolved with this, if i access url like xyz.com/invalid/test/ (adding extra parameters) then it's show blank white page instead of NotFound page ?

Comment: Not reproducible on my end.  Blank page seems like a failure unrelated to the beforeEnter code though.  Given a route like `xyz.com/invalid/test/` it should _only_ be hitting the notFound route since it's the only possible match.  Do you have any errors show up in your browser dev console when testing this? Something like `NotFound` component not being imported in your routes file could cause a failure like that, but it would also give an obvious runtime error.

Comment: Getting errors xyz.com/invalid/test/ ERR_ABORTED 404(not found) and Refused to  load script from xyz.com/invalid/js/app.js

Comment: is this result from using a production build or in dev?

Comment: using dev build